# PCP with commutative alphabet

Tags: undecidability

[Post's Correspondence Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) is known to be undecidable. A variant of PCP, namely [PCP with partially commutative alphabets](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13089-2_30) is also known to be undecidable.
Is the following variant also known to be undecidable?

**PCP with commutative alphabet.** 
Given and alphabet $\Sigma = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_K\}$ and $2N$ sequences $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_N, \delta_1, \delta_2, \ldots, \delta_N \in \Sigma^*$.
Determine if there is a sequence of integers $\{i_j\}_{j=1}^M$ such that for each $1 \leq j \leq M$, $i_j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ and for each $1 \leq m \leq K$,

$\#(a_m, \gamma_{i_1} \gamma_{i_2} \ldots \gamma{i_M}) = \#(a_m, \delta_{i_1} \delta_{i_2} \ldots \delta_{i_M})$
where $\#(a, w)$ denotes the number of occurences of the symbol $a$ in the string $w$.

Notice why I used the term "commutative" for the alphabet: the order of the symbols in the strings does not matter; only the counts need to be equal.

In general, is any variant of (unbounded) PCP with commutative alphabet known to be decidable or undecidable?

Comment: In the paper you link it is mentioned (on page 358): "The only known (positive) result related to PCP with commutative alphabet is of [12] and deals with the Parikh equivalence, i.e. the case when the p.c. alphabet is fully commutative."

Answer (score 3):

Let  $\gamma_{ij},\delta_{ij}$ be the number of characters $\sigma_j$ in $\gamma_i,\delta_i$ (respectively). Then the PCP instance has a solution if there exist non-negative integers $a_1,\ldots,a_N,b_1,\ldots,b_N$ such that for all $j \in \{1,\ldots,K\}$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \gamma_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^N b_i \delta_{ij}.
$$

While integer programming is hard in the general case, in this case we can solve it using linear programming in polynomial time. I claim that the program above has a solution in non-negative integers iff it has a solution in non-negative *reals*. One direction is obvious. In the other direction, suppose that the linear program corresponding to the integer program above (replacing non-negative integers with non-negative reals) is feasible. Then there is a solution for the program above in the non-negative *rationals* (every vertex of the polytope would do). Multiplying this solution by a common denominator, we obtain a solution of the original integer program.